# My Portal's MSSQL and vBulletin's MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, iis, vbulletin

I have developed a Portal using Microsoft ASP.NET and MSSQL. Now, I want to include vBulletin to my site for that purpose I need to have PHP and MySQL(or MSSQL will do?). With single login feature for both the Portal and Forum.

I have hosted my site on Dedicated IIS webserver hosted on MS Server 2008. 
I can install PHP on it. (and MySQL too if required)

The problem here is how can I integrate the user's of my portal with vBulletin forum??

Is there any way to Install vBulletin using IIS+PHP+MSSQL? 
or 
I have to use IIS+PHP+MysQL and integrate users of users of both the databases? (HOW?)

Answer (score 0):

At the moment vBulletin only supports MySQL.  There is talk of adding support for other databases however right now with all versions of VB MySQL is your only option.  So without heavily modifying VB this cannot use MSSQL (in fact I would strongly recommend that you don't even try embarking on that)

The other complication is that you are using two different code frameworks, PHP for vBulletin and ASP.NET (C#?) for your portal.  All these frameworks can sit together on the same dedicate box but you need them to communicate with each other.

With all this in mind the easiest way of having SSO across the two platforms (portal & vbulletin) would be to use the vBulletin user table in MySQL for your portal authentication.  There is a .NET MySQL driver that you can use for this purpose and running the necessary queries via that, from ASP.NET, should be fairly simple.

The only other thing that you will have to consider is a user logging in on your portal page not having to relog when they go to the forums.  This can be done by setting cookies etc so you will have to look at vBulletins login.php script to work out how these are handled.

There is also another option, that you may or may not want to consider (depending on how much work you have put into your portal ;)).  There is already a free portal product for vBulletin called vbAdvanced:

http://www.vbadvanced.com/

This may already meet your portal requirements and is developed specifically for vBulletin.

Comment: You are right I am thinking for the same. I can integrate the point my portal's user database to one used by vB. OR I am thinking of registering users from portal and at the same time running register.aspx (will put data in MSSQL) and register.php (will put data in MySQL) and same for login. Can you tell me which would be better (in terms of security, speed and complexity)??